# Created index based on different dates

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have the following data which retrieve the 2 last events based on `time` from an influxdb. Now I would like to add index with last event = 1 and previous event = 2. The index would apply when `account_entity`, `base_ccy`, `source` are the same but the date is different. `last` can be ignored for the index logic.

```
   account_entity base_ccy           last     source       time
 0            CORP      BTC          23444     KRAKEN      2019-04-25
 1            CORP      BTC       23434555     KRAKEN      2019-04-26
 2            CORP      ETH      123423444     KRAKEN      2019-04-25
 3            CORP      ETH      1231,3423     KRAKEN      2019-04-26
 10            PTE      BCH     23543.7667     BITSTAMP    2019-06-04
 11            PTE      BCH              4     BITSTAMP    2019-06-05
 24            PTE      BTC     2345.67677     BITSTAMP    2019-04-26
 25            PTE      BTC     8745           BITSTAMP 2019-04-27
```

I would like to add a column which tell what is the index.
The additional column would be:

```
index
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code (not sure if right logic but works):

```
print(df.groupby(['account_entity', 'base_ccy']).cumcount().sub(1).abs().add(1))
```

Output:

```
0     2
1     1
2     2
3     1
10    2
11    1
24    2
25    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Nice, thank you.  this worked for me `data['index'] = data.groupby(['account_entity', 'base_ccy', 'source']).cumcount(ascending = False)`

Comment: @mamadede Haha i was hacking it :P